# How to Update Meta Tags in my site designed in MODX Revolution 2.5.7?

Tags: tags, seo, meta-tags, meta, modx

I'm using MODX Revolution 2.5.7 version for my site.

But unable to update the Meta tags. I searched a YouTube video & follow their given steps But still no success.

I have attached below 2 snaps..

1st for updating the Meta tags & second is published page after saving the metas.

Picture of Dashboard while updating the Meta tags:

[image: Picture of Dashboard while updating the Meta tags]

Picture after updating the Meta Tags:

[image: Picture after updating the Meta Tags]

Answer (score 1):

It seems as you have confused template tags in your html. It should be

```
<meta name="description" content="[[*description]]"/>
```

And you are likely to have:

```
<meta name="description" content="[[*longtitle]]"/>
```

that's why you see long title where description should go.

Comment: Yes, My Meta Title is shown in Meta Description after updating But Meta Title & Keywords are disappear. How can I fix this issue? Any help will highly appreciated.

Comment: There is a template for the whole page in modx (BaseTemplate in your case). That template is usually divided into chunks. You are likely to have a chunk named "header" or something like this. You can modify it. If you want to add some new meta tags - just do it there like I showed before. You have template tags like [[*description]] at your disposal at https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/commonly-used-template-tags So. if you need title in your page, add  <title>[[*pagetitle]]</title> in the corresponding template/chunk.

Answer (score 1):

it looks to me like your cache needs to be cleared. (both browser & modx) - if you are using a CDN (i.e. cloudflare) or other caching service - clear that too.

your tags should look like:

```
<meta name="description" content="[[*description]]"/>

<meta name="keywords" content="[[*introtext]]"/>
```

...for the setup you are using.

You could also setup a template variable for the keywords (or any other meta information) and out put it like this:

`<meta name="keywords" content="[[*keywords]]"/>`

(assuming you named the variable "keywords")

There are also quite a few SEO/Meta extras available for modx ~ just search the extras directory.